# create_function with default parameter values?

Tags: php, parameters, create-function

Ok, I'm looking into using `create_function` for what I need to do, and I don't see a way to define default parameter values with it.  Is this possible?  If so, what would be the best approach for inputting the params into the `create_function` function in php?  Perhaps using `addslashes`?

Well, for example, I have a function like so:

```
function testing($param1 = 'blah', $param2 = array())
{
    if($param1 == 'blah')
        return $param1;
    else
    {
        $notblah = '';
        if (count($param2) >= 1)
        {
            foreach($param2 as $param)
                $notblah .= $param;

            return $notblah;
        }
        else
            return 'empty';
    }
}
```

Ok, so how would I use `create_function` to do the same thing, adding the parameters and their default values?

The thing is, the parameters are coming from a TEXT file, as well as the function itself.
So, wondering on the best approach for this using `create_function` and how exactly the string should be parsed.

Thanks :)

Comment: are you, by any chance, already using php5.3? If so, have a look at http://de2.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php - you might also be interested in the Strategy pattern http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering a function created with `create_function` this way :

```
$func = create_function('$who', 'echo "Hello, $who!";');
```

You can call it like this :

```
$func('World');
```

And you'll get :

```
Hello, World!
```

Now, having a default value for a parameter, the code could look like this :

```
$func = create_function('$who="World"', 'echo "Hello, $who!";');
```

Note : I only added the default value for the parameter, in the first argument passed to create_function.

And, then, calling the new function :

```
$func();
```

I still get :

```
Hello, World!
```

i.e. the default value for the parameter has been used.

So, default values for parameters work with `create_function` just like they do for other functions : you just have to put the default value in the list of parameters.

After that, on how to create the string containing the parameters and their values... A couple of string concatenations, I suppose, without forgetting to escape what should be escaped.

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is coming from a text file, so it could be like this for the parameters:  `$who = 'World'`, would this work in there also, or is there a function to substitute single quotes for double quotes?  Or should I use `addslashes` for this?

Comment: If you get this into a `$params` variable, you could use that `$params` variable as first parameter to `create_function` : its content is exactly what should be used there.

Comment: Thank You Very Much, so I don't need to escape any characters in the parameters than right?

Comment: 1 last thing, sorry, so I don't have to escape any characters in the parameters than right?

Comment: As long as your file contains a portion of valid-PHP code for parameters, I don't think you'd have to escape anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create an anonymous function? The `create_function` is used to create the anonymous functions. Otherwise you need to create function normally like:

```
function name($parms)
{
   // your code here
}
```

If you want to use the `create_function`, here is the prototype:

```
$newfunc = create_function('$a,$b', 'return "ln($a) + ln($b) = " . log($a * $b);');
echo "New anonymous function: $newfunc\n";
echo $newfunc(2, M_E) . "\n";
// outputs
// New anonymous function: lambda_1
// ln(2) + ln(2.718281828459) = 1.6931471805599
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, trying to pass an array to a created callback function... I think I'll create a temporary variable... It's ugly but I have better to do then torture myself with slashes, my code is already cryptic enough the way it is now.

So, to illustrate:

```
global $tmp_someArray;
$tmp_someArray = $someArray;
$myCallback = create_function(
    '$arg1',
    '
          global $tmp_someArray;
          // do stuff with $tmp_someArray and $arg1....
          return($something);
    '
);
```